# TypeError - Router.use() requires a middleware function but got a undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

So am trying to create a RESTful api with express and nodejs. When i run npm start to start the server it throws an error saying Router.use() requires a middleware but got an undefined. Any ideas what could be the problew. My code is pasted below.

Thanks in advance

server.js

```js
import express from 'express';
import bodyParser from 'body-parser';
import { router as Orders } from './routes/order';

const app = express();

// PORT Number
const PORT = process.env.PORT || '3000';

//  Setting up the body parser middleware
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

// Setting up middleware for a specific route
app.use('/api', Orders);

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`Running application on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

order.js route

```js
import express from 'express';

const router = express.Router();

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.send('Hello from api');
  next();
});

export default router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a default export:

```
export default router;
```

You should be importing it using the syntax:

```
import Orders from './routes/order'
```

Or, if you want to keep the import syntax the same, you can change the export so that it is not a default:

```
export { router }
```